# Choosing series element that > 0

Tags: pandas

I hope to get element that >0 for boxplot with the following code:

```
import seaborn as sns
d=pd.DataFrame({"r":[1,2,3]})
sns.boxplot(x=d[(d["r"]>0)])
```

This gives error

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

How to resolve it?

Comment: Try `sns.boxplot(x=d.loc[d["r"]>0, 'r'])`

Comment: Also: `sns.boxplot(data=d[(d["r"]>0)], x='r')`